# Reactjs Onclick is not workin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Regards!!

why onClick is not working in my code, I have this:

```
App.js,  this file is the father of file Tasks.js

          deleteTask = (id) => {
            console.log("clicked");
          }
    
      render() {    
        return(       
        <div> 
          <TaskForm addTask={this.addTask} />
          <Tasks tasks={this.state.tasks} deteleTask={ this.deleteTask } />
        </div>
        )
      } 

in my Tasks.js, this file is the Father of file Task.js

render(){
    return this.props.tasks.map(task => 
    <Task 
        task={task} 
        key={task.id} 
        deleteTask={this.props.deteleTask} 
        />);                    
}

in task.js 

render(){

    const {task} = this.props;

    return(
        <div style={ this.StyleCompleted() } >
            {task.title} - 
            {task.description} - 
            {task.done} - 
            {task.id} 
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <button style={btnDelete}  onClick={this.props.deleteTask} value={task.id}> 
                Delete X               
            </button>       
        </div>
       
    )
}
```

so I have a function in my App.js it's called 'deleteTask', so through parameters I'm passing the function 'deleteTask' from father(App.js) to son(tasks.js), then I'm passing the funstion from father(Tasks.js) to son (Task.js), so idea is when I clicked on "Delete X"  in the console should be seen "clicked".... but it's not workins....

I also used this method onClick={ () => this.props.deleteTask }  but it didn't work to :-(

Comment: `onClick={ () => this.props.deleteTask() }`

Comment: @ritaj `onClick={ () => this.props.deleteTask() }` should be an equivalent to `onClick={ this.props.deleteTask }`

Comment: @ritaj : and it still won't work, since you need to pass `task.id` as a parameter

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov in that case `id` would be `undefined` but the `console.log` should work anyway

Comment: does an error occur?

Comment: @messerbill : I may suspect, ***real*** `deleteTask()` does something different, than logging static message to the console.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov even if that would be the case the function would be called and executed. There may occur an error later on due to the missing parameter, but as long as the `console.log` line appears before any potential errors it should log its message

Comment: onClick={ () => this.props.deleteTask() } I have this error react-dom.development.js:4091 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.deleteTask is not a function

Comment: the function execute this code:

Comment: const newTasks = this.state.tasks.filter( task => task.id !== id );     
console.log(newTasks);

Comment: whith console.log() I onli want if the object is working

Comment: but it not working